# How to set up htaccess rewrite for multiple variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, affiliate

I originally created SEO friendly links for my site. I wanted my links for my coupon code site to look like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/site/bodybuilding.com
```

So I did a rewrite in the htaccess that worked:

```
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ retailertest3.php?linklabel=$1
```

Now, I'm working on creating a custom affiliate program. I want users to be able to send traffic to a link like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/site/bodybuilding.com?ref=john
```

How would I go about modifying the rewriterule so that the ref variable is passed properly to retailertest3.php?

Also, after I get the value of the ref variable and do some stuff with it, is it possible to do a 301 redirect back to the original URL of:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/site/bodybuilding.com
```

I'm trying to avoid possible canonical issues like this, as well as keep everything looking clean.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!!

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ retailertest3.php?linklabel=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: I simply added [QSA] to the rule and it worked:

RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ retailertest3.php?linklabel=$1 [QSA]